# Как с помощью ajax Laravel вытащить данные взависимый select?

Tags: laravel

Есть форма с которой я отправляю запрос, и получаю данные. То есть я выбираю отдел и мне нужно что бы из бд подтянулся руководитель. Сейчас он тянет поле user_id, как сделать так чтобы он вытаскивал имя из таблицы user.
Модель подразделения

```
public function user()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Контролер запроса

```
   class AjaxManager extends Controller
{
    public function application($id){

        $department = Department::where('id','=' ,$id)->get();

        return response()->json($department, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

}
```

Вызов

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $('#form_application_create #department_id').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{route('employee_selection.application.index')}}/ajax/' + $this.val(),
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {}
        })
            .done(function (department) {
                $('#form_application_create #manager').empty();
                department.forEach(function (department) {
                    $('#form_application_create #manager').append('<option value="' + department['user_id'] + '" data-percent=" ">' + department['user_id'] + '</option>');
                })
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log('error');
            });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно догадался то:

```php
class AjaxManager extends Controller
{
    public function application($id){

        $department = Department::where('id','=' ,$id)->with(['user'])->get();

        return response()->json($department, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

}
```

```js
(function ($) {
    $('#form_application_create #department_id').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{route('employee_selection.application.index')}}/ajax/' + $this.val(),
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {}
        })
            .done(function (department) {
                $('#form_application_create #manager').empty();
                department.forEach(function (department) {
                    $('#form_application_create #manager').append('<option value="' + department['user_id'] + '" data-percent=" ">' + department['user']['name'] + '</option>');
                })
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log('error');
            });

    });
})(jQuery);
```